# hide row in listview

Tags: android, listview, hide, element

I have adapter. Unfortunately, this solution is not good because the list is empty, you can scroll through the area, how to prevent it?

This code adapter:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
                ViewHolder viewHolder;
                View rowView = convertView;
                int NumberOfWords = GetNumberOfWords(position);

                if(rowView == null)
                {
                        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list, parent, false);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                        viewHolder.MainText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.MainText);
                        viewHolder.ItemText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ItemText);
                        viewHolder.Selection = (CheckedTextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.DictionaryCheck);
                        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }
                else
                {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
                }

                if(NumberOfWords == 0)
                {
                        rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                        rowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.MainText.setText(values[position]);
                        viewHolder.ItemText.setText("Zawiera słów : " + NumberOfWords);
                        viewHolder.Selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.Selection.setChecked(IsInSelected(position));
                }
                return rowView;
        }
```

Comment: so you want to disable the scrolling when the list is empty?

Comment: I want to show in the list only selected items, the slider is to be active, now instead of hiding places are empty fields.

Comment: can you post your getCount() mehod?